# locking inside system calls using kernel modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have replaced the sys_open system call in the system call table to implement a tallying system. What lock must I use? The spin_lock_irqsave() function freezes the system. I am using an Intel Core i3-4330 on Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae.

Partial but revelant code:

```
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(spin);
static int tally = 0;

static asmlinkage long my_sys_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, int mode)
{
    unsigned long fl;
    spin_lock_irqsave(&spin, fl); // system freeze

    tally++;

    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&spin, fl);

    printk("sys_open used %i times\n", tally);

    return old_sys_open(filename, flags, mode);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for which you are not using 'mutex_lock'? http://www.hep.by/gnu/kernel/kernel-locking/API-mutex-lock.html

Comment: Strange. Your code looks good. How do you know that the freeze is happening at `spin_lock_irqsave`? If you comment out the locking code, it doesn't freeze? Is there any other code which uses `spin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't solve your locking problem directly, as others have stated in the comment of your question, the code looks good.  But as an alternative you can use the `atomic_t` type as your counter and avoid the spinlock all together.  Something along the lines of:

```
atomic_t tally = ATOMIC_INIT(0);
```

and then to increment the value use:

```
atomic_inc(&tally);
```

Finally you can use `atomic_read(&tally)` when you want to finally read the value

You can read more about atomic [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/atomic_ops.txt).

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing? What is a 'tallying' system? How have you concluded the spin_lock_irqsave line is causing trouble?

First off, at syscall entry point interrupts are enabled so this would should be spin_lock_irq instead. But this code has 0 reason to care about disabling interrupts, so this should be spin_lock. Except you are only incrementing a counter, which can be done with atomic ops, hence no locking is required.

Regardless, the code should not have caused trouble, so something else is going wrong. Enabling debugging facilities in the kernel config and possibly obtaining a vmcore (read about kdump) could sched light here.